# Jupyter Notebook load_ext signature

Tags: python, import, jupyter-notebook

A while ago I found the following [website](http://ramiro.org/notebook/wikipedia-most-revisions/), from which I copied the source code and pasted it into my own `jupyter notebook`.

```
%load_ext signature
%matplotlib inline

import requests
import helpers

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from lxml import html
from datetime import datetime

# Set style and meta info.
mpl.style.use('ramiro')
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_reports/Pages_with_the_most_revisions'
end_date = '27 March 2015'
chartinfo = 'Author: Ramiro Gómez - ramiro.org • Data: ' + url.replace('https://', '')
infosize = 12

# Extract first wikitable from page
xpath = '//*[contains(@class, "wikitable")]'
tree = html.fromstring(requests.get(url).text)
table = tree.xpath(xpath)[0]
raw_html = html.tostring(table)

# Create dataframe from html table
df = pd.read_html(raw_html, header=0, index_col='Page')[0]
df.index = df.index.map(lambda x: x.replace('_', ' '))
df.head(10)
```

Now I rediscovered this notebook and wanted to run it. However, it doesn't work:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-cd5561f41831> in <module>()
----> 1 get_ipython().magic('load_ext signature')
    2 get_ipython().magic('matplotlib inline')
    3 
    4 import requests
    5 import helpers

    /home/xiaolong/development/anaconda3/envs/jupyter/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in   magic(self, arg_s)
2161         magic_name, _, magic_arg_s = arg_s.partition(' ')
2162         magic_name = magic_name.lstrip(prefilter.ESC_MAGIC)
-> 2163         return self.run_line_magic(magic_name, magic_arg_s)
2164 
2165     #-------------------------------------------------------------------------

/home/xiaolong/development/anaconda3/envs/jupyter/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in   run_line_magic(self, magic_name, line)
2082                 kwargs['local_ns'] = sys._getframe(stack_depth).f_locals
2083             with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2084                 result = fn(*args,**kwargs)
2085             return result
2086 

<decorator-gen-64> in load_ext(self, module_str)

/home/xiaolong/development/anaconda3/envs/jupyter/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/magic.py in <lambda>(f, *a,  **k)
    191     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
    192     def magic_deco(arg):
    --> 193         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
    194 
    195         if callable(arg):

    /home/xiaolong/development/anaconda3/envs/jupyter/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/extension.py in   load_ext(self, module_str)
    64         if not module_str:
    65             raise UsageError('Missing module name.')
    ---> 66         res = self.shell.extension_manager.load_extension(module_str)
    67 
    68         if res == 'already loaded':

    /home/xiaolong/development/anaconda3/envs/jupyter/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/extensions.py in     load_extension(self, module_str)
    82             if module_str not in sys.modules:
    83                 with prepended_to_syspath(self.ipython_extension_dir):
    ---> 84                     __import__(module_str)
    85             mod = sys.modules[module_str]
    86             if self._call_load_ipython_extension(mod):

    ImportError: No module named 'signature'
```

I don't know why this module is missing or what it actually does.

How can I fix this and get the code running?

Additional info:

I have the jupyter notebook in a virtual environment, which has the following packages:

```
# packages in environment at /home/xiaolong/development/anaconda3/envs/jupyter:
#
abstract-rendering        0.5.1               np110py35_0    defaults
alabaster                 0.7.7                    py35_0    defaults
anaconda                  2.5.0               np110py35_0    defaults
anaconda-client           1.2.2                    py35_0    defaults
argcomplete               1.0.0                    py35_1    defaults
astropy                   1.1.1               np110py35_0    defaults
atlas                     0.27.0                    <pip>
babel                     2.2.0                    py35_0    defaults
beautifulsoup4            4.4.1                    py35_0    defaults
bitarray                  0.8.1                    py35_0    defaults
blaze                     0.9.0                     <pip>
blaze-core                0.9.0                    py35_0    defaults
bokeh                     0.11.0                   py35_0    defaults
boto                      2.39.0                   py35_0    defaults
bottleneck                1.0.0               np110py35_0    defaults
brewer2mpl                1.4.1                     <pip>
calysto-prolog            0.8.3                     <pip>
cffi                      1.2.1                    py35_0    defaults
clyent                    1.2.0                    py35_0    defaults
colorama                  0.3.6                    py35_0    defaults
configobj                 5.0.6                    py35_0    defaults
cryptography              1.0.2                    py35_0    defaults
curl                      7.45.0                        0    defaults
cycler                    0.9.0                    py35_0    defaults
cython                    0.23.4                   py35_0    defaults
cytoolz                   0.7.5                    py35_0    defaults
datashape                 0.5.0                    py35_0    defaults
decorator                 4.0.6                    py35_0    defaults
docutils                  0.12                     py35_0    defaults
dynd                      f641248                   <pip>
dynd-python               0.7.1                    py35_0    defaults
emcee                     2.1.0                     <pip>
et-xmlfile                1.0.1                     <pip>
et_xmlfile                1.0.1                    py35_0    defaults
fastcache                 1.0.2                    py35_0    defaults
flask                     0.10.1                   py35_1    defaults
fontconfig                2.11.1                        5    defaults
freetype                  2.5.5                         0    defaults
futures                   3.0.3                    py35_0    defaults
ggplot                    0.6.8                     <pip>
gmpy2                     2.0.7                     <pip>
greenlet                  0.4.9                    py35_0    defaults
h5py                      2.5.0               np110py35_4    defaults
hdf5                      1.8.15.1                      2    defaults
idna                      2.0                      py35_0    defaults
ipykernel                 4.2.2                    py35_0    defaults
ipython                   4.1.1                    py35_0    defaults
ipython-genutils          0.1.0                     <pip>
ipython-notebook          4.0.4                    py35_0    defaults
ipython-qtconsole         4.0.1                    py35_0    defaults
ipython_genutils          0.1.0                    py35_0    defaults
ipywidgets                4.1.1                    py35_0    defaults
itsdangerous              0.24                     py35_0    defaults
jbig                      2.1                           0    defaults
jdcal                     1.2                      py35_0    defaults
jedi                      0.9.0                    py35_0    defaults
jinja2                    2.8                      py35_0    defaults
jpeg                      8d                            0    <unknown>
jsonschema                2.4.0                    py35_0    defaults
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py35_1    defaults
jupyter-client            4.1.1                     <pip>
jupyter-console           4.1.0                     <pip>
jupyter-core              4.0.6                     <pip>
jupyter-kernel-test       0.1                       <pip>
jupyter_client            4.1.1                    py35_0    defaults
jupyter_console           4.1.0                    py35_0    defaults
jupyter_core              4.0.6                    py35_0    defaults
libdynd                   0.7.1                         0    defaults
libffi                    3.0.13                        0    <unknown>
libgfortran               1.0                           0    defaults
libpng                    1.6.17                        0    <unknown>
libsodium                 1.0.3                         0    defaults
libtiff                   4.0.6                         1    defaults
libxml2                   2.9.2                         0    <unknown>
libxslt                   1.1.28                        0    <unknown>
llvmlite                  0.8.0                    py35_0    defaults
lmfit                     0.8.2                     <pip>
lxml                      3.5.0                    py35_0    defaults
markupsafe                0.23                     py35_0    defaults
matplotlib                1.5.1               np110py35_0    defaults
metakernel                0.11.5                    <pip>
metakernel-bash           0.11.3                    <pip>
mistune                   0.7.1                    py35_0    defaults
mkl                       11.3.1                        0    defaults
mkl-service               1.1.2                    py35_0    defaults
multipledispatch          0.4.8                    py35_0    defaults
nbconvert                 4.1.0                    py35_0    defaults
nbformat                  4.0.1                    py35_0    defaults
networkx                  1.11                     py35_0    defaults
nltk                      3.1                      py35_0    defaults
nose                      1.3.7                    py35_0    defaults
notebook                  4.1.0                    py35_0    defaults
numba                     0.23.1              np110py35_0    defaults
numexpr                   2.4.6               np110py35_1    defaults
numpy                     1.10.4                   py35_0    defaults
octave-kernel             0.13.2                    <pip>
odo                       0.4.0                    py35_0    defaults
openblas                  0.2.14                        3    defaults
openpyxl                  2.3.2                    py35_0    defaults
openssl                   1.0.2f                        0    defaults
pandas                    0.17.1              np110py35_0    defaults
patchelf                  0.8                           0    defaults
path.py                   8.1.2                    py35_1    defaults
patsy                     0.4.0               np110py35_0    defaults
pep8                      1.7.0                    py35_0    defaults
pexpect                   3.3                      py35_0    defaults
pickleshare               0.5                      py35_0    defaults
pillow                    3.1.0                    py35_0    defaults
pip                       8.0.2                    py35_0    defaults
ply                       3.8                      py35_0    defaults
psutil                    3.4.2                    py35_0    defaults
ptyprocess                0.5                      py35_0    defaults
py                        1.4.31                   py35_0    defaults
pyaml                     15.8.2                    <pip>
pyasn1                    0.1.9                    py35_0    defaults
pycosat                   0.6.1                    py35_0    defaults
pycparser                 2.14                     py35_0    defaults
pycrypto                  2.6.1                    py35_0    defaults
pycurl                    7.19.5.3                 py35_0    defaults
pyflakes                  1.0.0                    py35_0    defaults
pygments                  2.1                      py35_0    defaults
pymatbridge               0.5.2                     <pip>
pyopenssl                 0.15.1                   py35_1    defaults
pyparsing                 2.0.3                    py35_0    defaults
pyqt                      4.11.4                   py35_1    defaults
pytables                  3.2.2               np110py35_0    defaults
pytest                    2.8.5                    py35_0    defaults
python                    3.5.1                         0    defaults
python-contrib-nbextensions alpha                     <pip>
python-dateutil           2.4.2                    py35_0    defaults
pytz                      2015.7                   py35_0    defaults
pyyaml                    3.11                     py35_1    defaults
pyzmq                     15.2.0                   py35_0    defaults
qt                        4.8.7                         1    defaults
qtconsole                 4.1.1                    py35_0    defaults
readline                  6.2                           2    <unknown>
redis                     2.6.9                         0    <unknown>
redis-py                  2.10.3                   py35_0    defaults
requests                  2.9.1                    py35_0    defaults
rope                      0.9.4                    py35_1    defaults
rope-py3k                 0.9.4.post1               <pip>
satlas                    0.1.0b17                  <pip>
scikit-image              0.11.3              np110py35_0    defaults
scikit-learn              0.17                np110py35_2    defaults
scipy                     0.17.0              np110py35_1    defaults
setuptools                19.6.2                   py35_0    defaults
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py35_0    defaults
sip                       4.16.9                   py35_0    defaults
six                       1.10.0                   py35_0    defaults
snowballstemmer           1.2.1                    py35_0    defaults
sockjs-tornado            1.0.1                    py35_0    defaults
sphinx                    1.3.5                    py35_0    defaults
sphinx-rtd-theme          0.1.9                     <pip>
sphinx_rtd_theme          0.1.9                    py35_0    defaults
spyder                    2.3.8                    py35_0    defaults
spyder-app                2.3.8                    py35_0    defaults
sqlalchemy                1.0.11                   py35_0    defaults
sqlite                    3.9.2                         0    defaults
statsmodels               0.6.1               np110py35_0    defaults
sympy                     0.7.6.1                  py35_0    defaults
tables                    3.2.2                     <pip>
terminado                 0.5                      py35_1    defaults
threadpool                1.3.2                     <pip>
tk                        8.5.18                        0    <unknown>
toolz                     0.7.4                    py35_0    defaults
tornado                   4.3                      py35_0    defaults
tqdm                      3.8.0                     <pip>
traitlets                 4.1.0                    py35_0    defaults
unicodecsv                0.14.1                   py35_0    defaults
util-linux                2.21                          0    <unknown>
werkzeug                  0.11.3                   py35_0    defaults
wheel                     0.29.0                   py35_0    defaults
xlrd                      0.9.4                    py35_0    defaults
xlsxwriter                0.8.4                    py35_0    defaults
xlwt                      1.0.0                    py35_0    defaults
xz                        5.0.5                         1    defaults
yaml                      0.1.6                         0    <unknown>
zeromq                    4.1.3                         0    defaults
zlib                      1.2.8                         0    <unknown>
```

Answer (score 5):

I face this problem too , did a little exploration, and solved it.

Please read about `%load_ext` [magic](http://ipython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/config/extensions/index.html#getting-extensions). Apparently `signature` is an extension, to use it you need to install it first.

Now the problem is you need to find the code of signature.

It took me longer to find the code. The tutorial is written by Ramiro Gómez, I found his webpage on [github and the script](https://github.com/yaph/ipython-notebooks/blob/master/signature.py).

To install you can use `%install_ext` magic in the iPython shell.

Comment: So it's just a custom extension to display the original author's signature... You can as well just comment the line off and the rest of the code will run alright.

Comment: %install_ext is deprecated now? :\

Answer (score 0):

Install:

```
conda install -c conda-forge python-magic
```

Create the file "signature.py" ->link [Ramiro Gómez's script](https://github.com/yaph/ipython-notebooks/blob/master/signature.py) and add it to your folder. Done!